# Camel Http Component throwing SocketException if idle for 30 mins

Tags: java, http, soap, apache-camel, socketexception

I am trying to get response from a Soap web service using Camel 2.11.1 http component .It works fine normally. But if I keep it idle for say 30 mins and retry the same request, it hangs and after few mins throws SocketException :

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_55]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:152) ~[na:1.7.0_55]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122) ~[na:1.7.0_55]
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:442) ~[na:1.7.0_55]
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(nInputRecord.java:480) ~[na:1.7.0_55]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:927) ~[na:1.7.0_55]
```

Can anyone suggest a solution for this weird behavior? The Soap web service is hosted on Consumer side and is not available.I tried getting tcpdump from wireshark and it shows re-transmission packets. However I do not get this problem if I keep my system idle for 30 mins for other services.

Comment: It even works fine, after hanging once. Please help !

Comment: Maybe you have a firewall that disconnects connections after 30 min idle.

Comment: Firewall in my network or at server's network?
Can I simply close the TCP connection and open one for every request.
I tired setting "Connection" :"close" and server stopped sending keep-alive for headers. But still the problem persists.

Comment: Not a firewall problem. It works fine with other services.

Comment: How about implement a custom HttpConnectionManager which close the connection if the connection is idle for few mins?